# docker-credential-osxkeychain wants to use your confidential information

Tags: docker, macos-sierra

This has started happening recently after a docker update on my Macbook.
I am using Docker version 17.03.0-ce-mac2 on macos-sierra.

If I run a `docker build -t .` from a terminal I get a pop-up warning which says:

`docker-credential-osxkeychain wants to use your confidential information stored in mydomain.com in your keychain.
Do you want to allow access to this item?`

If I click 'deny' everything continues as normal without any issues. But I have to do this every time.

What does this mean ?

Comment: Happens for me as well on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in this particular release of Docker and that the new release 17.03.1-ce-mac5 is solving this issue.  There is a reference in the release notes: https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases/tag/v0.5.0

I just installed this release and I don't have this behaviour on my El Capitan install.

Comment: Can confirm it is fixed with version 17.03.1-ce-mac5